# How to export and import mysql data base from server using php

Tags: import, phpmyadmin, export

How to export and import mysql database from server using php?

Answer (score 1):

For export and import I use SSH command and it is very fast.

For Export Databse :

```
$db_host = '15.2.4.222’;                  // database server
$db_user = 'db_user';                    // database user name
$db_pwd = 'dbpasword';             // database password
$db_schema = 'db_name';         // name of database to be exported

    exec(sprintf(
    'mysqldump --opt -h%s -u%s -p%s %s | gzip > /var/www/vhosts/yoursitename.com/httpdocs/ backups_db/backup_filename_%s.sql.gz',
    $db_host,
    $db_user,
    $db_pwd,
    $db_schema,
    $today
    ));
    exit;
```

Now For import :

```
$db_host = '15.2.4.222’;                  // database server
$db_user = 'db_user';                    // database user name
$db_pwd = 'dbpasword';             // database password
$db_schema = 'db_name';         // name of database to be exported

// Command to restore database      
exec("mysql -h [db server ip here] -u [db username here] –p[password here] [db name here] < /var/www/vhosts/yoursite.com/httpdocs/foldername_wherefile_exist/filename.sql");
// Example:
exec("mysql -h 15.2.4.222 -u db_username -ptestpassword test_db_name < /var/www/vhosts/phproots.com/httpdocs/backups_db/filename.sql");
```

Please use it for backup and restore databse.